CMake reverse dependency issue
The question is about a C application using CMake as a build system.
Suppose I have a library, A. It depends on other libraries, say, B, C and D. As such, somewhere in my CMake scripts I have:
target_link_libraries(A B C D)

One of these, say C, in turn requires (pseudo-) random number generation.
In an actual application I need true random number generation, whereas for tests I want to use pseudo-random number generation for reproducibility. Thus I have two libraries, Rtrue and Rpseudo, which implement true and pseudo-random number generation, respectively, using exactly the same API.
I have a target to test library A, and in that case I need pseudo-random number generation, so I should link to Rpseudo:
target_link_libraries(testA A Rpseudo)

This works fine in macOS. However, in Linux, I'm getting an undefined reference for my (pseudo-)random number generation function. Building verbosely so I can examine the command line when compiling testA, it links to (in this exact order) A Rpseudo B C D. The linking order is the same in macOS and Linux.
Copying the command line and changing the order to A B C D Rpseudo, linking succeeds in Linux.
I've tried many variants of the target_link_libraries(testA ...) command, but nothing gets the link order to A B C D Rpseudo.
I'm really at a loss as to how to express this correctly in CMake. Obviously I can't do something like target_link_libraries(C Rpseudo) since for other executables I need to link to Rtrue instead, and vice-versa.
What's the right way to express this kind of dependency and ensure the correct linking order?

Are you using static libraries on Linux? Also, show us the complete error message, where it happens, and what you were linking to at the time.....
